# Adding a json to a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file that contains weather data. There are 30 days of data and 24 hours for each day. Each day contains data for the day I.E. Sunrise and each hour contains data for the hour I.E. precipitation.

I am trying to create a dataframe that contains one row for each hour. Every row contains columns that contain data for the current day aswell.

Here is the code I have:

```
    weather_list = []
    for day_dict in weather['data'][1]:
        weather_dict = {}
        for day_key, day_val in day_dict.items():
            if not isinstance(day_val, list):
                # Daily info
                weather_dict[day_key] = day_val
            else:
                if len(day_val) == 1:
                    # Astronomy i.e. sunrise sunset for the day
                    weather_dict.update(day_val[0])
                else:
                    # Hourly weather info
                    for hour in day_val:
                        for hour_key, hour_val in hour.items():
                            if isinstance(hour_val, list):
                                if len(hour_val) == 1:
                                    # weatherIconUrl and weatherDesc
                                    # Maybe be more than one value in the future
                                    weather_dict[hour_key] = hour_val[0]['value']
                            else:
                                weather_dict[hour_key] = hour_val
                        weather_list.append(weather_dict)
    weather_df = pd.DataFrame(weather_list)
```

This code works in that it add the daily data fine but when it goes to add the hourly data. It't all the same I.E. It contains 24 rows of hour 23.

Here is a sample of my data.

`{\"data\":{\"request\":[{\"type\":\"City\",\"query\":\"Cowansville, Canada\"}],\"weather\":[{\"date\":\"2009-07-04\",\"astronomy\":[{\"sunrise\":\"04:09 AM\",\"sunset\":\"07:42 PM\",\"moonrise\":\"05:59 PM\",\"moonset\":\"01:27 AM\"}],\"maxtempC\":\"17\",\"maxtempF\":\"63\",\"mintempC\":\"16\",\"mintempF\":\"60\",\"totalSnow_cm\":\"0.0\",\"sunHour\":\"11.5\",\"uvIndex\":\"0\",\"hourly\":[{\"time\":\"0\",\"tempC\":\"16\",\"tempF\":\"60\",\"windspeedMiles\":\"5\",\"windspeedKmph\":\"8\",\"winddirDegree\":\"197\",\"winddir16Point\":\"SSW\",\"weatherCode\":\"353\",\"weatherIconUrl\":[{\"value\":\"http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0025_light_rain_showers_night.png\"}],\"weatherDesc\":[{\"value\":\"Light rain shower\"}],\"precipMM\":\"0.4\",\"humidity\":\"98\",\"visibility\":\"10\",\"pressure\":\"1005\",\"cloudcover\":\"87\",\"HeatIndexC\":\"16\",\"HeatIndexF\":\"60\",\"DewPointC\":\"15\",\"DewPointF\":\"60\",\"WindChillC\":\"16\",\"WindChillF\":\"60\",\"WindGustMiles\":\"10\",\"WindGustKmph\":\"15\",\"FeelsLikeC\":\"16\",\"FeelsLikeF\":\"60\"},{\"time\":\"100\",\"tempC\":\"16\",\"tempF\":\"60\",\"windspeedMiles\":\"5\",\"windspeedKmph\":\"8\",\"winddirDegree\":\"201\",\"winddir16Point\":\"SSW\",\"weatherCode\":\"353\",\"weatherIconUrl\":[{\"value\":\"http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0025_light_rain_showers_night.png\"}],\"weatherDesc\":[{\"value\":\"Light rain shower\"}],\"precipMM\":\"1.2\",\"humidity\":\"99\",\"visibility\":\"9\",\"pressure\":\"1005\",\"cloudcover\":\"91\",\"HeatIndexC\":\"16\",\"HeatIndexF\":\"60\",\"DewPointC\":\"15\",\"DewPointF\":\"60\",\"WindChillC\":\"16\",\"WindChillF\":\"60\",\"WindGustMiles\":\"9\",\"WindGustKmph\":\"15\",\"FeelsLikeC\":\"16\",\"FeelsLikeF\":\"60\"},{\"time\":\"200\",\"tempC\":\"16\",\"tempF\":\"60\",\"windspeedMiles\":\"5\",\"windspeedKmph\":\"9\",\"winddirDegree\":\"204\",\"winddir16Point\":\"SSW\",\"weatherCode\":\"356\",\"weatherIconUrl\":[{\"value\":\"http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0026_heavy_rain_showers_night.png\"}],\"weatherDesc\":[{\"value\":\"Moderate or heavy rain shower\"}],\"precipMM\":\"2.0\",\"humidity\":\"99\",\"visibility\":\"8\",\"pressure\":\"1005\",\"cloudcover\":\"96\",\"HeatIndexC\":\"16\",\"HeatIndexF\":\"60\",\"DewPointC\":\"16\",\"DewPointF\":\"60\",\"WindChillC\":\"16\",\"WindChillF\":\"60\",\"WindGustMiles\":\"9\",\"WindGustKmph\":\"15\",\"FeelsLikeC\":\"16\",\"FeelsLikeF\":\"60\"}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was updating `weather_dict` while it was in the list. I needed to create a deep copy of the object so I wasn't referencing the same object.

I refactored the code to look look like this.

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

weather_list = []
for day_dict in weather['data'][1]:
    # Create a dictionary that only contains the day data
    day_data = copy.deepcopy(day_dict)
    del day_data['hourly']
    day_data = flatten_json(day_data)

    for hour_dict in day_dict['hourly']:
        hour_data = flatten_json(hour_dict)
        day_data.update(hour_data)
        day_hour_data = copy.deepcopy(day_data)

        weather_list.append(day_hour_data)
weather_df = pd.DataFrame(weather_list)
```